# Adjective for "containing an ellipsis?"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Some phrases have three dots indicating an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) at the end of a statement/sentence.

How can one refer to such a phrase/sentence?

I naturally want to refer to them as "*ellipsed* sentences," but that is clearly wrong as [*ellipsed*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ellipsed) refers to having a regular oval shape (i.e., the shape of an [*ellipse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse)).

Does such a word exist?

Comment: I'd called them clipped or abridged.

Comment: How about *ellipticated*?

Comment: Also FYI: [ellipse](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ellipse) (n.) [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ellipse):
1753, from French *ellipse* (17c.), from Latin *ellipsis* "ellipse," also, "a falling short, deficit," from Greek *elleipsis* (see [*ellipsis*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ellipsis)). So called because the conic section of the cutting plane makes a smaller angle with the base than does the side of the cone, hence, a "falling short."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**elliptical**

> adjective, Also, **elliptic**
>
> 2. pertaining to or marked by grammatical ellipsis.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/elliptic)

Comment: huh, I just assumed these words only worked for their better known meaning (i.e., relating to an ellipse or shape of an ellipse). Seems like at least a few dictionaries mention their secondary use as a reference to ellipses like you mention..Thanks!!

Comment: And what about the case when I want to emphasize the transformation into ***becoming** elliptic*? The term *elliptic* coveys the notion of ***being in** a state of* and I'd like to imply ***changing into** a state of*. Would it work with *ellipted*? As in *I'm **ellipting** this text, so it's **ellipted** by me*`?